# Is it possible to integrate my opencart application with Quickbook desktop software?

Tags: php, mysql, api, opencart, quickbooks

When I make a sale on my opencart web site, I would like to be able to make the corresponding journal entry in my accounting books in desktop quickbook software.

Can I do it on free API..? or any ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + Quickbooks integration (API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151216/php-quickbooks-integration-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Custom software which connect your Opencart Store and your desktop quickbook. This custom software will automatically connect to your QuickBooks and enter data as you needed. I am using software from this guys - http://www.quickbookintegration.com/

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I've worked with quickbooks, but yes you could code it to insert the data automatically into their software providing you can use the wrapper code provided in Ben Lee's link